# Continuos scanning on Bluez 5.32 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am using Raspberry Pi(Model B+ V1.2) with Raspbian image having kernel version 3.18.7+ and Bluez 5.32. I am trying to enable continuous LE Active scan in Bluez and taking a look at doc/adapter-api.txt, I find no parameter to set LE scan scan interval or scan window. Checking adapter.c, I find that `adapter->no_scan_restart_delay` parameter if set to true should trigger continuous scan.

However even after setting it to `TRUE`, I find that trigger of next scan after default 10 sec takes around 2 sec to restart. I am not sure if this is expected behavior but I get same results when I use tools/btmgmt utility. It scans for 10 seconds and pauses for 5 seconds. But if I set the  `no_scan_restart_delay` flag in `adapter.c` to `TRUE` it still pauses to ~2 seconds between consecutive scans.

Is there a way to trigger continuous active BLE scan in Bluez?